# Azure AD + security for small companies

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I seem to have got the role of Azure Admin by default. We are a small company of individual developers with no central storage or authentication. The only common point we have is office 365 email.

We dont have any shared servers or any of that sort of thing. What we do is, store everything in our local 'Code' folder under different projects and just use Azure DevOps to sync to cloud.

I am wondering if I need Azure AD in that instance?

We also have around 20 servers in cloud. We use an admin id to connect to these servers.

This is not a good practise as I understand.

I want a simple cost effective solution to be able to have 1 id per user who can be centrally authenticated and can then use their own id to login to each cloud server

I am happy to get a VPN in place so that each person can be given a private IP and then we can make our cloud into a private cloud. I noticed our VM's are currently constantly been hammered with logon requests as they are currently public cloud servers

Sorry if I am asking a lot here, but hoping for some quick pointers or links

Many Thanks
Manish

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are using office 365 and utilizing the mail services. You can create Azure  VM in azure and use separate credentials. But however you need to have Azure Active Directory either p1 or p2 license and Azure AD DS services. Kindly check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/join-windows-vm) to get information about joining your VM to Azure AD DS. If you have any further queries kindly let me know